# MobileFirst Login Issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

Do we need to call WL.Client.Login API before submitLoginForm in MobileFIrst 7.1.0 while using Formbasedauthentication (LoginModule = LDAP).

IBM documentation does not mention it but we found that if we do not call it MobileFirst Server does not send any Challenge.But we call that before submitLoginForm we receive all challenge handler and got authenticated from LDAP.

Please Advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

`submitLoginForm()` is the step where the client side code ( challengehandler) sends the credentials to the server. This is in case of Form based login.

The challenge will come from the server as a result of the application connecting to the server by:

- WL.Client.connect(). In this case, if the application is protected, server throws the challenge.
- WL.Client.login(realmName). If this is a custom realm, the server sends a challenge to be handled.
- Invoking a protected resource using WLResourceRequest. The server responds with a challenge.
- When user enters wrong credentials to an earlier challenge

When the challenge comes, you handle it in the challengehandler. The handleChallenge flow in the client ends with the client submitting the credentials in the login form and sending it to the server using the API - `submitLoginForm()`.

Comment: Thanks vivin so you mean we have to call WL.Client.Login before submitLoginFailure, but do we need to call it everytime we do login or just once.

Comment: No.What I meant is you should handle the challenge when it comes from the server. You will get a challenge when a protected application connects to the server or when you invoke a protected resource. When the challenge comes, you handle it. You do not have to call WL.Client.login () just before submitLoginForm. The login() call will result in a challenge, which you will handle in the challengehandler - and will end when you submit the credentials with submitLoginForm().